# Undefined room_limit in JavaScript WebRTC application using socket.io and mediasoup - How to properly set and access room limit?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webrtc, mediasoup

I'm trying to create a room limit for my application, and I want it to show up on the room list, but it says "Available Rooms." I tried the code below, and I thought that it would work. The room limit is supposed to be defined as how many users the user wants to join the room. I see the following output:

```
Join Room 6b3d03ab-507b-4186-9ab3-865468393a8f
dsaDSADs
Room Limit: undefined
```

Here's the code I've tried:below is room.js

```
'use strict';
// ... (rest of code) ...
module.exports = class Room {
    // ... (rest of code) ...
    getRoomLimit() { // method to get the room limit
        return this.room_limit;
    }
    // ... (rest of code) ...
}
```

below is room list html

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>JoinUrSpheres Rooms</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Available Rooms</h1>
  <div id="room-list"></div>
  <script>
    // ... (rest of code) ...
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is part of the form where room_limit is gathered on the form

```
<body onload="initClient()">
    <!-- ... (rest of code) ... -->
    <div class="input-box">
        <input id="initInputRoomLimit" required type="number" name="room_limit" class="init-common" min="1" onkeyup="checkFields()" />
        <label>Room Limit</label>
    </div>
    <!-- ... (rest of code) ... -->
</body>
```

Below is server.js room limit related code

```
// ... (rest of code) ...
const roomList = new Map();

app.get('/joinurspheres', (req, res) => {
  // ... (rest of code) ...
});

app.post('/api/rooms', (req, res) => {
  // ... (rest of code) ...
  const roomLimit = req.body.room_limit; // use the same name as in the client-side HTML form

  const room = {
    description: description,
    room_limit: parseInt(roomLimit), // Convert roomLimit to integer, notice the consistent lowercase here
    // other properties...
  };
  // ... (rest of code) ...
});

// ... (rest of code) ...
```

below is more related server.js related to room limit

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('A user connected');

    socket.on('createRoom', async ({ room_id, description, room_limit }, callback) => {
        socket.room_id = room_id;

        if (roomList.has(socket.room_id)) {
            callback({ error: 'already exists' });
        } else {
            log.debug('Created room', { room_id: socket.room_id, description: description, room_limit: room_limit });
            let worker = await getMediasoupWorker();
            roomList.set(socket.room_id, new Room(socket.room_id, worker, io, description, room_limit));
            callback({ room_id: socket.room_id });
        }
    });
```

Please let me know what the error is. My code is a lot more extensive; this is just the relevant code for the room_limit.